# Storing and retrieving session Laravel Passport Token in React SPA App

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-redux, laravel-passport

I want to implement a simple SPA app with Passport Auth API,

I tried localStorage (in js) to store the token there, but it seems not secure. So I was looking for alternative.

btw. Laravel 5.8 react 16.8

```
export const LogIn = formValues => async dispatch => {
    connect.post('auth/login', formValues).then(response => {
        return response;
      })
      .then(json => {
        if (json.status === 200) {
         // alert("Login Successful!");

          let userData = {
            email: formValues.email,
            auth_token: json.data.access_token,
            timestamp: new Date().toString()
          };

          let appState = {
            isLoggedIn: true,
            user: userData
          };

          // save app state with user date in local storage
          localStorage["appState"] = JSON.stringify(appState);

          return userData;

        } else alert("Login Failed!");

      })
      .catch(error => {
        let appState = {
          isLoggedIn: false,
          user: {}
        };

        localStorage["appState"] = JSON.stringify(appState);

        alert(`An Error Occured! ${error}`);
      });
};
```

I can Login and Logout from my APP. Only upon refresh I am losing the tokens. I am lost here for 2 weeks already :(

Answer (score 1):

What you need to to is to persist your authenticated state.

You can do this by creating a context provider and accessing the values inside your component (check out [React Redux Connect API](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) or check out [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html))

Comment: hey mate I am using the same here! I believe that after refresh state and store will get reset to default, but i need to retain the auth state somehow

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out? Or do you need clarification with anything?

Comment: Oh, I think I will stick with redux-persist for a while